# How to create rounded wxBitmap buttons?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, onpaint, wxtextctrl

```
CustomBitmap *bitmapCtrl1 = new CustomBitmap(mainPanel, bitmap1, id+1, rollover_bitmap1, NULL, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(125, 125));
```

`CustomBitmap` class is derived from `wxControl`. And this is my OnPaint function.

```
void CustomBitmap::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxPaintDC dc((wxWindow *) this);
    SetTransparent(0);
    
    if (m_enter)
    {
        dc.DrawBitmap(m_bmpmouseover, 0, 0, true);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_leftdown || m_rightdown){
            dc.DrawBitmap(m_bmpclick, 0, 0, true);
        }
        else {
            dc.DrawBitmap(m_bmpstatic, 0, 0, true); 
        }
    }
#ifdef WX3 
    //dc.EndDrawing();
#else
    // dc.EndDrawing();
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't customize drawing of the native controls, they just are not made to cooperate with you. If you need round buttons, you will have to draw them and also handle input and generate events for them entirely yourself.

You may find `wxRendererNative` and `wxMouseEventsManager` helpful for drawing and input handling respectively.